# ng-disabled and form validation

Tags: angularjs

When using angular's (1.5) forms support, I would expect that when a field is disabled, it should not be marked as invalid, because the user cannot possibly change the value.

However, as seen in the plunker below, where a field is required, but can be switched from enabled to disabled and visa versa by the checkbox, the form validation result does not change, the whole form is still invalid, although the value cannot be changed if the field is disabled.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OMZkoPgPZcHjO67JF88c?p=preview

Together with showing validation messages and submitting the form this poses a problem in UX and flexibility to use the angular validations to determine the state of the form and if it is ok to "submit it" (send AJAX to the server).

(the code below is in the plunker, I just pasted it here, because the code is required when linking plunker)

```
<form name="vm.form" novalidate>
  <input ng-model="vm.model" ng-disabled="vm.disabled" required />
  <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.disabled" />Disable field</label>
</form>
Form is invalid: {{vm.form.$invalid}}
```

Comment: use $dirty  you can check whether the field is edited or not

Comment: if the ng-disabled is dynamic, than it does not matter, imagine: the user edits the field, then he chooses some other options that makes the field disabled, so it is invalid and dirty at the same time, on top of that disabled, and it still invalidates the whole form

Comment: so the thing you are asking is that when you disable the field angularJS should not validate it ??

Comment: and it should mark the form as valid ?

Comment: yes, for me that is a reasonable behavior, because the field cannot be possibly changed by the user when it is disabled. So why should it be validated, why couldn't the user submit the form, why should the validation messages be present...

Comment: I think you have to manually include a condition along with vm.form.$invalid && !vm.disabled  to checked for the form validations

Comment: you have to change the ngRequired value to true and false based on whether the checkbox is checked or not

Comment: This does not scale well.. imagine I have more fields like that or more validations (pattern, maxlength, ...). This will become messy condition hell.

Comment: see my answer bro  ..for that you to manually set up in your controller function ...directive would be the best

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106929/discussion-between-rajat-bhadauria-and-redhead).

Answer (score 0):

Ok preety much here you dont normally do ng-disabled on the fields just on like the submit button as shown:

```
  <input ng-model="vm.model" ng-minlength="4" ng-required="true"/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.disabled" ng-required="true"/>Disable field</label>
  <br><input type="submit" ng-disabled="vm.form.$invalid"/>
</form>
Form is invalid: {{vm.form.$invalid}}
</body>
</html>
```

Now if you try this it will work correctly as shown in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pE14KFn3lLQkTnTPZvCr?p=preview).

Comment: this was just the simplest example that shows the issue.. on top of that, the disabled field is needed by the business analytics and designers. Imagine a much bigger form where there are many fields and many conditions that can influence the submittability of the form.

Comment: Yes can you please post that "Big" form so i can help you @redhead. I know much more than only this..

Comment: Well, we are using angular-formly library for generating the forms, but this is really a problem with angular, so I posted it as that. Also we have a kind of a custom framework that is used throughout the application so we do not repeat code. The framework submits the form when it is $valid=true, but this issue totally disables that. I see that more as an angular design issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can manipulate the value of ng-required value based on whether the checkbox value is checked or not

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Asd as vm">
    <form name="vm.form" novalidate>

      <input ng-model="vm.model" ng-disabled="vm.checkbox" ng-required="vm.checkbox===false" />
      <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.checkbox" />Disable field</label>
    <input  ng-model="vm.other" required/>
    </form>
    Form is invalid: {{vm.form.$invalid}}

  </body>

</html>
```